# Can I set the default keyboard layout using kernel arguments while booting Linux Mint 17 Live USB?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-layout, live-usb

I have a USB flash drive that I'm using to boot machines with. It can boot with several GNU/Linux distributions, including Mint 17 [Cinnamon]. The only annoying factor is that I always have to change the keyboard layout once the desktop appears. I remember older versions of Ubuntu used to have a language/keyboard menu to set the language and keyboard layout before booting.

Does Linux Mint Live DVD also provide such a feature, i.e. (at least) change keyboard layout before booting? Ideally I'd write the necessary kernel arguments in the bootloader configuration file.

**EDIT**: Don't be misled by me using Live DVD / Live USB as I actually used live DVD ISO images that I extracted and configured for running off the USB flash drive. So the flash drive is not formatted with an ISO image but is partitioned with some extra, usable storage space.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `rd.vconsole.keymap=` (Or `vconsole.keymap=` if that does not work)

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/vconsole.conf.html